# How can I disable a UIButton until multiple TextFields are filled in with data (numbers)?

Tags: ios, swift, iphone

I have 3 UITextFields in my app and I need a user to fill in before he/she can see the UIButton which will calculate the result. I have tried a lot of different methods to resolve the issue but they don't seem to work and I can't quite understand some of them. I am sure there is a simple way to do that. P.S.: I don't use a storyboard

I have already tried to include UITextFieldDelegate, then writing a function, also used other ways, etc...

```
import UIKit
let Label: UILabel = {
    let f = UILabel()
    f.text = "Label"
    return f
}()
let textFiled1: UITextField = {
    let fw = UITextField()
    fw.keyboardType = UIKeyboardType.decimalPad
    return fw
}()
let textField2: UITextField = {
    let fh = UITextField()
    fh.keyboardType = UIKeyboardType.decimalPad
    return fh
}()
let textField3: UITextField = {
    let fa = UITextField()
    fa.keyboardType = UIKeyboardType.numberPad
    return fa
}()
class ViewController: UIViewController {
    let calculateButton: UIButton = {
        let c = UIButton()
        c.setTitle("Calculate", for: .normal)
        return c
    }()
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        setupLabel()
        setupTextFieldComponents()
        setupCalculateButton()
    }
    fileprivate func setupLabel() {
        view.addSubview(fLabel)
    }
    fileprivate func setupTextFieldComponents() {
        setupTextField1()
        setupTextField2()
        setupTexrField3()
    }
    fileprivate func setupTextField1() {
        view.addSubview(textField1)
    }
    fileprivate func setupTextField2() {
        view.addSubview(textField2)
    }
    fileprivate func setupTextField3() {
        view.addSubview(textField3)
    }
    fileprivate func setupCalculateButton() {
        view.addSubview(calculateButton)
    }
    @objc func calculateButtonPressed(sender: UIButton){
        let textfield1 = Float(textField1.text!)
        let textfield2 = Float(textField2.text!)
        let textfield3 = Float(textField3.text!)
        femaleMetaLabel.text = String(111 + (1.1 * textfield1!) + (1.1 * textfield2!) - (1.1 * textfield3!))
    }
}
```

User is supposed to enter numeric data in all three text fields in order to calculate the result. Is there a way to make an ERROR message pop out without an app crashing?

Comment: Our code is a complete mess. Can you edit it to make it readable?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Maxim you are almost there. Let me add a simple delegate in your code to achieve your goal.

Add code in your `textFieldDidEndEditing` delegate -

```
func textFieldDidEndEditing(textField: UITextField) {

    if (textField1.text?.count)! > 0 && (textField2.text?.count)! > 0 && (textField3.text?.count)! > 0 {

         calculateButton.isEnabled = true

    }else{

         calculateButton.isEnabled = false

    }
}
```

**Now time to calculate the result:**

```
@objc func calculateButtonPressed(sender: UIButton){

    if let inputOne = Float(textField1.text!), let inputTwo = Float(textField2.text!), let inputThree = Float(textField3.text!) {

          femaleMetaLabel.text = String(111+(1.1*inputOne)+(1.1*inputTwo)-(1.1*inputThree))

    }else{

        let alert = UIAlertController(title: "", message: "You entered invalid inputs", preferredStyle: .alert)

        alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Ok", style: .default, handler: nil))

        self.present(alert, animated: true)

    }
}
```

Hope it will help you. Let me know if you are still having any issue.

Answer (score 1):

When I am doing validation on text input that enables a button, I usually do something like this:

```
@IBOutlet weak var usernameField: UITextField!
@IBOutlet weak var passwordField: UITextField!
@IBOutlet weak var submitButton: UIButton!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    submitButton.isEnabled = false
}

override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(animated)

    NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self,
                                           selector: #selector(validateInput(_:)),
                                           name: UITextField.textDidChangeNotification,
                                           object: usernameField)
    NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self,
                                           selector: #selector(validateInput(_:)),
                                           name: UITextField.textDidChangeNotification,
                                           object: passwordField)
}

override func viewDidDisappear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewDidDisappear(animated)

    NotificationCenter.default.removeObserver(self)
}

@objc func validateInput(_ sender: Any?) {

    submitButton.isEnabled = false

    if let username = usernameField.text,
        let password = passwordField.text {

        // your validation rules will be more complex than this :D
        if username.count > 0 && password.count > 0 {
            submitButton.isEnabled = true
        }
    }
}
```

If what you need to do is pop an alert when the inputs are incorrect, simply substitute a call to a method like the one below, where you vaildate the user's input.

```
func showAlert() {

    let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Nope",
                                  message: "Your inputs were incorrect.",
                                  preferredStyle: .alert)

    alert.addAction( UIAlertAction(title: "Try again",
                                   style: .default,
                                   handler: nil) )

    self.present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```